# How to save graph from NetStream to gexf file?

Tags: java, netstream, netlogo, gephi

I am trying to save a GraphStream/NetStream from NetLogo do *.gexf file. Graph has constant number of edges and vertices. Thing that is changing is parameters of nodes/'turtles'. Currently, after each tick, I send information from NetLogo to localhost on port 2012 using:

```
gs:add-sender "sender" "localhost" 2012
```

I can receive GraphStream in java project:

create instance of CumulativeGraphAnalyser

```
NetStreamReceiver receiver = new NetStreamReceiver(2012);
new CumulativeGraphAnalyser(receiver, null);
```

and this is the CumulativeGraphAnalyser class

```
public class CumulativeGraphAnalyser extends SinkAdapter{
private NetStreamSender sender;
private Graph graph;
private String mySourceId;
private long myTimeId;
private int round;

public CumulativeGraphAnalyser(NetStreamReceiver receiver, NetStreamSender sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
    graph = new SingleGraph("cumulative graph", false, false);
    ProxyPipe pipe = receiver.getDefaultStream();
    pipe.addElementSink(graph);
    pipe.addElementSink(this);


    round = 1;
    mySourceId = toString();
    myTimeId = 0;
}

@Override
public void stepBegins(String sourceId, long timeId, double step) {

    for (Node node : graph.getNodeSet()){
        node.getAttribute("node-id");
        node.getAttribute("infected");
        (...)

    }
    System.out.println(round++);
}
}
```

There are all information I need in the 'graph' variable, but I don't know how to save the GraphStream to file (*.gxef) and after that import it in Gephi. The other option is to read the GraphStream in Gephi directly from localhost:2012. I found plugin which suppose to handle this task, but I don't know how to use it properly. 
I've searched and read lots of information about this problem, and I've tried to implement some solutions, but none of them doesn't come off.